# Setting up search page and filter (similar to ecommerce)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm building my first rails app and I'm trying to build the search page on an ecommerce type site. The idea is the model pulls all the data from the database according to the filter that is checked or selected on the view such as (category, sub-category, price, date, etc.)

I've watched railscasts on elasticsearch, solar, etc. They seem like they'd each work in this scenario but are they overkill? I'm just not sure what is the quickest and most scalable way to set up this search. I've read a little about the has_scope gem which seems like it would be one way but I can't find a good tutorial or documentation on has_scope. Can someone point me in the right direction for creating this search page? Should I build it out with has_scope, solar, or elasticsearch?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my own experience solr is the best search technology I've come across. It provides a feature called faceting which is what you are describing. You can read about it on their wiki here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview

The best solr gem I've come across is sunspot. It has a very easy to use DSL for interfacing with solr from a Rails app and hooks in to active record very easily. Take a look at their [github project page](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot). I think that will answer your question.

Comment: Perfect, this looks like exactly what I needed. I know this question is somewhat subjective but when you're learning to program these type of questions seem necessary when you don't know the best route. Thanks again.

Comment: I know, I was faced with the same problem when trying to decide between different technologies as well... Hopefully it works out for you.